# Using observable's to fetch data for many items and return it as a single map (angular 2)

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an array of ID's and for each ID I want to check if it's data is stored in local cache (If so, take it) or not (Fetch it from server).
At the end of the process I want to get a map witch holds all of the ID's and its resolved data.

Every thing Iv'e try so far didn't answer my requirements..
The closest thing I was manage to do is :

```
return this.userGroups$
  .switchMap(userGroupsSet => Observable.from(userGroupsSet[GROUP_LIST_TYPE[groupType]])
    .mergeMap(groupID => Observable.of(this.getGroupByID(<string>groupID, groupType)
      .map(groupData => {
        return {[<string>groupID]: groupData}
      })
      .catch(e => Observable.empty())))
    .combineAll()
    .map(groupsArray => {
      let groupsMap: Map<string, IGroupData> = new Map();
      for (let index in groupsArray) {
        let groupID = Object.keys(groupsArray[index])[0];
        groupsMap.set(groupID, groupsArray[index][groupID])
      }
      return groupsMap;
    })
  )


 getGroupByID(groupID: string, groupType: GROUP_LIST_TYPE): Observable<any> {
    return this.userGroups$
      .switchMap(userGroups => {
        if (userGroups['groupsData'].has(groupID))
          return Observable.of(userGroups['groupsData'].get(groupID));
        else
          return this.fetchSingleGroupData(groupID, groupType)
            .map(groupData => groupData)
            .catch(e => Observable.throw(e)
            )
      })
  }
  private fetchSingleGroupData(groupID: string, groupListType: GROUP_LIST_TYPE): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(URLS.AB_STATIC + "groups/" + groupID + ".json", false)
      .do(groupData => {
        this.userGroups$.dispatch({
          type: GROUPS_ACTIONS.CACHED_GROUP_DATA_FETCHED,
          payload: {
            groupID: groupID,
            groupData: groupData.json()
          }
        });
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(e => {
        if (groupListType != null)
          this.userGroups$.dispatch({
            type: GROUPS_ACTIONS.REMOVE_ID_FROM_LIST,
            payload: {
              groupID: groupID,
              groupList: groupListType
            }
          });
        return Observable.throw(e)
      })
  };
```

In the above code, The subscriber get's a map that the key is the group ID, and the value is the group data (If it was stored in cache) or an unresolved observable (If it's trying to fetch it from server).
I want to get the same think only that all of the value will be resolved (Both cached and new fetched).
It's worth to mention that when I have all data in cache, I'm getting the map exactly as I wanted, so the problem is with the fetching and resolving part..

How can I do it properly?
Also, any improvements to this code will be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify the question and answer here . Let me know if you need more info .

```
private cache = {};

public getData(ids: string[]){
    return Observable.from(ids)
        .flatMap((id: string)=>
            this.cache[id] ?
                Observable.of({id: this.cache[id]}) :
                this.http.get(url, {id: id })
                    .map(res => { id: res.json()})
                    .do(data => Object.assign(
                        this.cache,data }
                     )
            }
        )
        .reduce(Object.assign, {});
}
```